Read data from PubSub Topic and write those data into BigQuery through the Dataflow by using Python
I successfully created the Dataflow job, but it didn't complete as expected. It seems there might be an issue with reading data from Pub/Sub, which could be preventing the job from finishing correctly.
import os
import json 
import logging
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions, GoogleCloudOptions, StandardOptions
# from apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery import WriteToBigQuery
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from create_dataset_and_table_in_bq import create_bq_dataset_and_table
load_dotenv()

current_dir = os.getcwd()
gcp_credential_path = os.getenv('gcp_credential_path', '')
project_id = os.getenv('project_id', '')
topic_name = os.getenv('topic_name', '')
region = os.getenv('region', '')
bucket_path = os.getenv('bucket_path', '')
job_name = os.getenv('job_name', '')
dataset_id = os.getenv('dataset_id', '')
table_id = os.getenv('table_id', '')

# Get the root of the current drive
root_dir = os.path.splitdrive(current_dir)[0] + os.sep
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = os.path.join(root_dir, gcp_credential_path)
 
options = PipelineOptions()
google_cloud_options = options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions)
google_cloud_options.project = project_id
google_cloud_options.region = region
google_cloud_options.job_name = job_name 
google_cloud_options.staging_location = f"{bucket_path}/staging"
google_cloud_options.temp_location = f"{bucket_path}/temp"
options.view_as(StandardOptions).runner = 'DataflowRunner'
options.view_as(StandardOptions).streaming = True

def transform_data(element):
    print(f"Received message: {element}")
    return json.loads(element.decode('utf-8'))

dataset_created, table_created = create_bq_dataset_and_table(region, dataset_id, table_id)

# BigQuery schema
schema = ('primary_title:STRING, num_votes:INTEGER') 

subscription_name = f'projects/{project_id}/subscriptions/dataflow-insight-hub-pubsub-topic-2-sub'


with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
    (p
    | 'Read from Pub/Sub' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=f'projects/{project_id}/topics/{topic_name}', with_attributes=True)
    | 'Transform Data' >> beam.Map(transform_data)
    | 'Write to BigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            table=f"{project_id}:{dataset_id}.{table_id}",
            schema=schema,
            write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND
        )
    )

I tried using the following pipeline code for debugging purposes:
with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
        messages = p | 'Create Test Data' >> beam.Create([
            b'{"primary_title": "Test Movie", "num_votes": 1000}',
            b'{"primary_title": "Another Movie", "num_votes": 500}'
        ])
        (messages
        | 'Log and Transform Data' >> beam.Map(log_and_transform_data)
        | 'Write to BigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                table=f"{project_id}:{dataset_id}.{table_id}",
                schema=schema,
                write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND
            )
        )

The BigQuery table was created successfully, and the data was inserted correctly. However, I’m unable to determine why the original(above) job didn’t execute successfully. Could anyone help me troubleshoot this issue?

That is the expected behavior. Using PubSub as input results in a streaming pipeline. By definition it serves a continuos data stream and beam has no way of knowing that it is finished (in fact by definition it never finishes). Consequently, the pipeline also never stops. See programming guide and unbounded PCollection (link here)

what kind of errors have you seen from the logs? Since you use with_attributes=True, I guess element.decode('utf-8') should be element.data.decode('utf-8') .

Actually the job status always in running state, I did not found the cause except this log '"textPayload": "Autoscaling is enabled for Dataflow Streaming Engine. Workers will scale between 1 and 100 unless maxNumWorkers is specified."'
